# Pandas -- Join two data sets if dates are within a few days of each other

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to join to dataframes based on their dates. I have a column in each for date and time (formatted like the following)

> '%y-%m-%d'

and I would like to join the two datasets if their dates are 3 or less dates apart. Appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain a little more? Does your column contain the same date?

Comment: Read [how to ask a good question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)